# How can I remove list inside list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]`

How can I remove `[` character inside the list so I can get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

This is my code so far:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
new_a = []
for item in a:
    if len(item) > 1:
        for sub_item in item:
            new_a.append(sub_item)
    else:
        new_a.append(item)
print(new_a)
```

Then I got this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

But when I get the length of the inside list with `len(a[3])`, it returns `3`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225427/1138192

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Thank you for your comment, what a great post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `len` to check whether something is a list, you should use `isinstance`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
new_a = []
for item in a:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for subitem in item:
            new_a.append(subitem)
    else:
        new_a.append(item)
```

See @Always Sunny's comment for even simpler ways of doing this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extend()`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
new_a = []
for item in a:
    try:
        len(item)
        new_a.extend(item)
    except:
        new_a.append(item)
print(new_a)
```

Or you can use `type()` if you want to check item is list or not:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
new_a = []
for item in a:
    if type(item) == list:
        new_a.extend(item)
    else:
        new_a.append(item)
print(new_a)
```